# Local VM setup using Puphpet is ignoring the subdomains.htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, vagrant, virtual-machine, puphpet

I have setup a local VM using Puphpet. My file structure is as follows:

```
|-www
     |- public
         -.htaccess
         - index.php
     | -subdomain
         -.htaccess
         - index.php
```

Here are the relevant bits from my config.yaml:

```
modules:
    - rewrite
vhosts:
    fj3ju1mwry6l:
        servername: main.dev
        serveraliases:
            - www.main.dev
        docroot: /var/www/public
        port: '80'
        setenv:
            - 'APP_ENV dev'
        directories:
            zfy5qmype3xj:
                provider: directory
                path: /var/www/public
                options:
                    - Indexes
                    - FollowSymlinks
                    - MultiViews
                allow_override:
                    - All
                require:
                    - all
                    - granted
                custom_fragment: ''
        engine: php
    3xbo0zhpbo5g:
        servername: subdomain.main.dev
        docroot: /var/www/subdomain
        port: '80'
        directories:
            otngayglj5ug:
                provider: directory
                path: ''
                options:
                    - Indexes
                    - FollowSymlinks
                    - MultiViews
                allow_override:
                    - All
                require:
                    - all
                    - granted
                custom_fragment: ''
        engine: php
        custom_fragment: ''
mod_pagespeed: 0
```

In each .htaccess I have placed:

```
deny from all
```

Visiting main.dev results in forbidden which is correct, however, visiting subdomain.main.dev displays the index.php. Anybody know the .htaccess is being ignored by the second vhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so incase anybody else experiences the same thing. The second vhosts conf file (found at /etc/httpd/conf.d/xxxx.conf) did not have anything declared under Directories (I assume there must be a bug with Puphpet or Vagrant). I added the following (taken from the first vhosts conf):

```
<Directory "/var/www/school">
 Options Indexed FollowSymlinks MultiViews
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
</Directory>
```

And now both htaccess files are being picked up.

**EDIT**

Ok, so after all that I noticed this line in my config yaml (path):

```
otngayglj5ug:
            provider: directory
            path: ''
            options:
```

After filling that in and re-provisioning it worked as expected.